# DocuSign API - Implicit Grant

Tags: docusignapi

We are developing a Salesforce component that can be used to display all envelopes and status related to a customer account record. The envelopes are generated and linked via custom field to the account record through a custom 3rd party application. We would like for the component to not require a login to DocuSign for the logged in user and just display the envelopes. So we're planning on using a Service User to callout to DocuSign to retrieve the envelopes.

My question is, is Implicit Grant the way to go for this? or JWT Grant? And what URI parameter values (such as scope) are key to getting a token?

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?
    response_type=token
    &scope=YOUR_REQUESTED_SCOPES
    &client_id=YOUR_INTEGRATION_KEY
    &state=YOUR_CUSTOM_STATE
    &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consider using the DocuSign Apex Toolkit. That would save you time and work.

Here is information about authentication - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/how-to/authenticate/